# ARM Template : Get an App Client Id by either App Name or App ID URI

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-rm

I was wondering if there was a way to get an App Client Id by using either it's App Name or App ID URI in ARM template (maybe by using a reference function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get the Client id via the App name or App ID URI.

The AD App is a resource in Azure AD, it is not a resource in the subscription, ARM template is for the resources in Azure subscription.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview

> Azure Resource Manager is the deployment and management service for Azure. It provides a consistent management layer that enables you to create, update, and delete resources in your Azure subscription.